# CodeIgniter 2: Cannot load any controller, libraries etc on Linux (Debian)

Tags: codeigniter

I am using

> Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
>
> PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze13

and for main idea for problem see below

my problem is same as define here [Extended Controller class not found - stumped!](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/97145/)

> Then I proceeded to extend the controller class with only a
>   constructor to keep it simple:

```
<?php


class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

> Then in the ‘application/controllers/welcome.php’ controller I changed
>   the name of the “Controller” class it extends to my new extended class
>   “MY_Controller”

```
<?php

class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{
    public function Welcome()
    {
        parent::__construct();    
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

> Then I run the site and I get
>
> Fatal error: Class ‘MY_Controller’ not found in
>   /application/controllers/welcome.php
>   on line 4

this error only showing on live server, it is working fine on localhost and also working on Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) but not on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian).

i also tried change `parent::__construct();`  with `parent::Controller();` but same error.

any solution thanks

Comment: your file should be named “MY_Controller” with a Capital “MY_C”.

Comment: but it is also working on Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) but not on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian).

and i have number of libraries, controller etc.! what will be the simplest & quickest solution. Thanks

Comment: o sorry i m using newer version with 
MY_Controller extends CI_Controller

Comment: yes same setting which is require for newer version & it is working fine on localhost and also working on Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) but not on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian).

Comment: oops buddy i just copy from link i specified but now i have confirmed that I am using newer version & it is working fine on localhost and also working on Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) but not on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian).

Comment: yes buddy both are on same version

Comment: This cannot be a **CodeIgniter 2** application since in 2.0 the application directory was moved outside of the system directory. Unless you moved it back for some reason? This path `/home/joseph/public_html/samp/system/application/controllers/welcome.php` shows that the application directory is inside the system directory.

Comment: o bro i told many many times that I just copied the main idea is how CI-2 can work on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put class **MY_Controller** (as MY_Controller file) in **application/core** folder (CI version 2.0 or higher)
With lower version, put in **application/libraries**

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use lower case for libraries name while load and also the file name.